# How to transfer file between two browsers with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, api, webrtc

In WebRTC, There have three main JavaScript APIs

1. MediaStream
2. RTCPeerConnection
3. RTCDataChannel.

Now, I'm try to develop, **File Transfer** between two browsers. Firstly, connect each browser with PeerConnection. And then, desired file are added with (Browse). And, send to with RTCDataChannel.

How can I develop this web application?

Comment: Also check out http://sharefest.me. Repo is at https://github.com/Peer5/Sharefest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this tutorial help you:-- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-file-broadcast-works.html